# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0. Error - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, expandablelistview

I'm trying to get the position id of a child in an expandableListView and start another class based on what child is clicked on and I'm doing that like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onChildClick(parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SavedEntries.class);
        i.putExtra("_id", id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        return super.onChildClick(parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
    }
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x17.projects.strikezone/com.x17.projects.strikezone.SavedEntries}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.x17.projects.strikezone.SavedEntries.getDateRow(SavedEntries.java:56)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.x17.projects.strikezone.SavedEntries.onCreate(SavedEntries.java:48)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-05 13:14:28.232: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  ... 11 more
```

This is where I'm sending the id to:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong("_id") : null;

    private void getDateRow()
    {
        Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchRow(mRowId);
        date = mCursor.getString(0); //Line 56, this is where the error occurs.
        mCursor.close();
    }
```

And here's the query for above:

```
public Cursor fetchRow(long rowId)
    {
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT date FROM entry WHERE _id=" + rowId, null);
        if(cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Why am I getting this error? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The cursor is on a null position. Loop through the cursor to fetch rows.

```
while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    date = mCursor.getString(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not getting any rows in Cursor. Make sure fetchRow(...) really returning some data. Is date field of String type?

Comment: Yes, the date field is a String. I checked the cursor count and it's 0, so that's why this error is occurring. How else can I get the id from the child which is clicked on to pass it to SavedEntries.class?

Comment: Debug and see whether  id is getting required value in onChildClick method or not.

Comment: For some reason groupPosition, childPosition and id are all getting a 0 value when onChildClick is called.

Comment: You need to find out why it is, I don't see any issue with your database retrieval logic pasted here. As you as you fix this other issue, it should work fine.

Comment: I was using a ListView to begin with and it worked completely fine. But when I changed it to ExpandableListView I started having this issue. So maybe this method isn't being called correctly or something? Since it's not giving me the id of the child position.

Comment: http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.htmlRefer this link, it may help you. If already referred, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

In the getDateRow method call the `mCursor.moveToFirst()` method before getting anything from it. It's best if you use it as condition since `mCursor.moveToFirst()` returns a boolean value that will be true if the cursor can move to first and false if the cursor cannot.
Here's what I mean:

```
   private void getDateRow(){
        Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchRow(mRowId);
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()){
        date = mCursor.getString(0);
        }
        mCursor.close();
    }
```